# How to display text according to the td width

Tags: html, text, html-table

i have set my `td` to certain `width`. i want to display text inside the `td`. i want that when the `text` is **longer than the td width** it will **cut** it or put ... at the end of text. so that the text will display **one line only** and **not wrap** it. How can i do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this using [CSS3 text-overflow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp) method.

```
text-overflow:ellipsis;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179962/how-to-auto-resize-html-table-cell-to-fit-the-text-size)

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/ABapAJi/1/edit)

Set style as

```
td {
  white-space: nowrap
}
```