# Remove unnecessary left space in table

Tags: html, css, html-table

How to get rid of left space so that text remains right aligned ? Unnecessary space is marked red in picture.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ta2vzuta/

```
<table style="width: 100%">
  <tr>
    <td class="labels"> some text here </td>
    <td> input field </td>
    <td class="labels"> some text here </td>
    <td> input field </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="labels"> text </td>
    <td> input field here </td>
    <td class="labels"> text here </td>
    <td> input field </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image: text example]

**EDIT**: Is it possible that the `<td class=labels>` will be adjusted to text length ? So that you don't need to set the fixed length ?

Comment: you are using <table> and it take its own space. You can specify the width of the <td>. Like this <td width:"100px !important" class="labels"> some text here </td>

Comment: Yes, but I want to use this `<table>` with width = 100%

Comment: Set the width according to yor text : <td width:"100px !important" class="labels"> some text here </td>

Comment: Yes, it's a possible solution. But what if text length is >  100px ? Is it possible to  adjust the table width to text length ?

Comment: you can give the width in "%" too... it will adjust according to the table with. but it will add space on left.. better go width "px" and adjust the size according to text

Comment: Text is written in multiple languages, so you don't know the right width. But I think I'll do it as you propose if there'll be no another solution.

Comment: is the text is loading dynamically..

Comment: yes the text is loading dynamically. It's label for input field.

Comment: on which environment your working on??

Comment: It's dialog, with labels and input fields.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Auto resize HTML table cell to fit the text size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179962/how-to-auto-resize-html-table-cell-to-fit-the-text-size)

Comment: Calculate the each text length whcih dynamically added and add the width for each on basis text length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In table cells, the `width` property only specifies a preferred width. But  if you use the default [automatic table layout](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#auto-table-layout), the cells will grow to be at least the minimum width required by the contents.

So you can use

```css
.labels {
  width: 0;            /* As narrow as possible */
  white-space: nowrap; /* Without inserting line breaks */
}
```

```css
.labels {
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%">
  <tr>
    <td class="labels"> some text here </td>
    <td> input field </td>
    <td class="labels"> some text here </td>
    <td> input field </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="labels"> text </td>
    <td> input field here </td>
    <td class="labels"> text here </td>
    <td> input field </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

use a combination of `width:50%` on `td` and `width:auto` on `.label` 
like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/grassog/udhwh388/2/